# Android user authentication

Tags: android, authentication, android-authenticator

I have creted some android application, that use web services for getting user information.

What I normally do is to pass the username and password in the request, whenever a web service is called.
Probably this practice is not so safe, since for each request, the password is sent.

What are the most used method for authenticate the user?

Answer (score 0):

Probably,You should use sha-512 or bcrypt for hashing,so that  you can protect from hacking.

Answer (score 0):

what i used for my app user authenticate is Socket connection . Use [SSLSocket](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html)